# Maximum number of component in UIPickerView

Tags: ios

I want to know what is the maximum number of Components can be added to UIPickerView.

Is there any limit ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation doesn't specify a maximum limit. So probably a the limit would be size of NSInteger.

[UIPickerView component size](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIPickerView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIPickerView/numberOfComponents)

Comment: and what about UITableView ..

Comment: UITableView is the same as well. The limit is so huge, because you can use reusable cells in the background. That is why you don't run out of memory.